# TP-LINK 740n router doesn't boot after bad firmware flash

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware

I was trying to flash back the stock firmware (from DD-WRT) to my tplink 740n router, but I got bad flash, and the router now doesn't boot, it behaves exactly just in the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N539Oei5Ezc

Could some one guide me to the correct and maybe easiest way to fix it?

Some infos:

TL-WR740N Ver: 4.23

https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/TP-LINK_TL-WR740N

Comment: What model version of the `TP-Link 470N` do you have?  Update your question to include this information.  Link to the DD-WRT documentation for your router, I am interested in what image file you attempted to use exactly

Comment: I have been unable to find a DD-WRT image find that indicates it specifically supports DD-WRT.

Comment: OK now I bricked my router completely while trying to sold pins to connect using rs232, but I will not delete the question just in case some one else had the same problem. I didn't understand exactly what do you mean? what infos you need? and the image of stock firmware or from ddwrt?

Comment: My comment is clear.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You changed the model number, so confused;

Comment: Right, sorry for that